# Button hitArea not moving

Tags: javascript, button, phaser-framework

With the Phaser 3 engine:

I have a side scrolled game. Mario like.
I made a pause button with two frames.
All objects which need to be shown on the HUD are added to an container called HUD.
Including the pauzeButton.

It works to pause the game with pausing all animations and physics.
(Because pausing and resuming scene did not really work, it wouldn't resume after pausing.)

All code is at the moment in the create function and I do not work with classes.

BUT…
When the character moves to the right and the camera moves to follow the character the button remains on place in the HUD, but the area where you can click for the pointerdown function to work is FIXED and does not move with it.

So lets say pauseButton is at 100, 10
And player moves 50 to the right.
The sprite will be on 150, 10
The area which can be clicked will be on 100, 10

How do I resolve this?

```
pauseButton.setHitArea(new Phaser.Geom.Rectangle(
    pauseButton.x - pauseButton.width / 2,
    pauseButton.y - pauseButton.height / 2,
    pauseButton.width,
    pauseButton.height
));
```

```
function update() {
  // Update the position of the pause button based on the HUD container position
  pauseButton.x = hud.x + 350;
  pauseButton.y = hud.y + 100;
}
```

```
pauseButton.input.hitArea.setTo(-pauseButton.width/2, -pauseButton.height/2, pauseButton.width, pauseButton.height);
```

```
pauseButton.input.hitArea = new Phaser.Geom.Rectangle(0, 0, pauseButton.width, pauseButton.height);
```

```
pauseButton.setHitArea(pauseButton.getBounds());
```

```
pauseButton.setInteractive({
    hitArea: pauseButton.getBounds(),
    hitAreaCallback: Phaser.Geom.Rectangle.Contains,
    cursor: 'pointer'
});
```

```
level1.update = function() {
    pauseButton.hitArea.x = pauseButton.x - pauseButton.width / 2;
    pauseButton.hitArea.y = pauseButton.y - pauseButton.height / 2;
};
```

tried al the above!
The only thing I expected is that the area where you click in will not remain fixed.
But moves with the sprite and the HUD, so wherever I walk with the character the pause button remained clickable.

Extra info:

```js
gameLevel1.create = function() {
    this.physics.world.setBounds(0, 0, 1600, 600);

    background = this.add.image(400, 300, 'background');
    score = 0;
    scoreText = this.add.text(16, 16, 'score: 0', { fontSize: '32px', fill: '#000' });
    wichLevel = this.add.text(300, 16, 'Level 1', { fontSize: '16px', fill: '#000' });

    pauseButton = this.add.sprite(350, 100, 'pauseSprite', 0).setScale(1);
    pauseButton.setInteractive({ cursor: 'pointer' });
    pauseButton.on('pointerdown', () => {
        if (this.anims.paused)
        {
            this.anims.resumeAll();
            console.log("play");
            this.physics.resume();
        }
        else
        {
            this.anims.pauseAll();
            console.log("pause");
            this.physics.pause();
        }
    }, this);
    pauseButton.on('pointerover', () => { pauseButton.setFrame(1); });
    pauseButton.on('pointerout', () => { pauseButton.setFrame(0); });
    
    hud = this.add.container(0, 0, [background, scoreText, wichLevel, pauseButton]);
    hud.setScrollFactor(0);

    player = this.physics.add.sprite(50, 50, 'playerSprite');
    player.setBounce(0);
    player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
    player.body.allowGravity = false;

    stars = this.physics.add.group({
        key: 'starSprite',
        repeat: 11,
        setXY: { x: 12, y: 0, stepX: 0 }
    });

    stars.children.iterate(function(child) {
        child.setBounceY(Phaser.Math.FloatBetween(0.4, 0.8));
    });

    bombs = this.physics.add.group();

    this.physics.add.overlap(player, stars, collectStar, null, this);

    this.physics.add.collider(player, platforms);
    this.physics.add.collider(stars, platforms);
    this.physics.add.collider(bombs, platforms);
    this.physics.add.collider(player, bombs, hitBomb, null, this);

    camera = this.cameras.main;
    camera.setBounds(0, 0, 1600, 800);
    camera.startFollow(player, true, 0.05, 0.05, 0, 0);

    cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();   
};
```

Character moves to the right:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEj7k.png)

Explaining what i mean, visually:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4ZCj.png)

Comment: Why do you need/want to set the `hitArea`? What gameObject are you using? Can you share the code where you are createing the `pauseButton` GameObject?

Comment: If you would look at both the images, I just added, I think it wil be clarified what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that what you are trying is not possible, in this specific way *([check the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Container.html#setScrollFactor__anchor))*.  You might be able to do it like that, but it would be very complicated.

The easy solution is to use two `scene` at the same time. One for the HUD and one for the Game. In this manner the HUD scene would not move *(and you can lay it out, without special calculations)*

**Here a demo showcasing this, two scene approach:**

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    physics: { default: 'arcade'},
    scene: [{
        key: 'HUD',
        active: true,
        create: hud_create,
    },{
        key: 'Game',
        active: true,
        create,
    },],
    banner: false
}; 

function hud_create(){
      this.add.text(10, 30, 'HUD')
        .setScale(1.5)
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'})
        .setInteractive({ cursor: 'pointer' });
                
    this.add.text(10, 160, 'press SPACE to start move ' )
        .setScale(1)
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});
}

function create () {
    this.add.text(10, 10, 'GAME ' . repeat(15))
        .setScale(1.5)
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});

    let player = this.add.rectangle(10, 100, 10, 10, 0xffffff);
    this.cameras.main.startFollow(player, true, 0.08, 0.08);
    
    this.physics.add.existing(player)
    
    this.input.keyboard.on('keydown-SPACE', _ => {
        player.body.setVelocityX(50)
    });
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

**Update, answer to comment:**

I don't really know a better solution, since `start`and `launch` only accept on scene key as mentioned in [the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Scenes.ScenePlugin.html#launch__anchor), that said if you want to keep everything together for readability, I would suggest something like this:

On **StartButton** click, just start both scenes with `launch` and close the *MainMenu* scene with `stop`:

```
   this.scene.launch("hudScene");
   this.scene.launch("level1");
   // close the current scene
   this.scene.stop(this.scene.key);
```

It is not better, than your solution, but like this you would keep all the opening and closing logic for starting the game in one place *(the main menu scene)*.

> I have usually one Main Scene, that is in the background and doesn't display anything, it only manages all the other scenes, that have to be opened and closed and also handles any data, that has to be passed to scenes, or the webserver. *(This setup is pretty complicated, and only useful for "larger" games, with many scenes)*

Comment: This is interesting. So i can run multiple scenes paralell. 
I am going to try this.

Comment: @MC20222023IN yes you can use several scenes, this makes it easier to seperate several parts of your game _(like game state management, HUD's, popups, background music and more)_.

Comment: I still have a problem testing your solution. I have an main menu wich has a startbutton with a pointerdown function. I am trying to run both scenes with this code: this.scene.start(["hudScene", "level1"]);

It gives me the hudScene, not the level1 scene. The hudScene contains my background, all text and both buttons.

Comment: Fixed this with this scene.launch("scene"); at the end of the first scene.
Now I have to make the pauzeButton freeze everything from the other scene. And make shure the scoretext in the hud scene is updated with what happens in level 1 scene. Feels like a lot more work.

Comment: But looking at my specific problem. That is resolved!! Now if my character moves around the HUD moves with it, like before. But now the clickable area also moves with it.

So it makes me happy :)
Thank you @winner_joiner.

Comment: If you have a better way instead of scene.launch("scene"); I really would like to hear it.

Comment: @MC20222023IN there is not really a better solution, but I added an alternative option to keep the scene launching in the same function